# How do I use the HTML/CSV reporters in pa11y with GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions, pa11y

I'm trying to get pa11y to output HTML and CSV reports.

Here's the errors:

> Unable to load reporter "csv"

> Unable to load reporter "html"

I have pa11y configured to generate `cli`, `csv`, and `html` reports, but only the `cli` report is output correctly.

My `pa11yconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "standard": "WCAG2AAA",
  "level": "notice",
  "defaults": {
    "chromeLaunchConfig": {
      "args": [
        "--no-sandbox"
      ]
    },
    "reporters": [
      "cli",
      "csv",
      "html"
    ],
    "runners": [
      "axe",
      "htmlcs"
    ],
    "timeout": 1000000,
    "wait": 2000
  }
}
```

And I'm running pa11y like this:

```
pa11y-ci --sitemap "$SITEMAP_URL"  > "$OUTPUT_DIR/success-pa11y-report.txt" 2> "$OUTPUT_DIR/failures-pa11y-report.txt"
```

This command is being executed as part of GitHub Actions, which looks like this:

```
  - name: Install pa11y.
    run: npm install -g pa11y-ci
  - name: 'TEST: Run pa11y tests.'
    run: my-pa11y-script.sh
```

My understanding is that the [reporters are now bundled with pa11y](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y/tree/master/lib/reporters), so how can I get pa11y to recognize them?

Comment: Is there any chance that you're running `pa11y-ci` but checking the documentation for `pa11y` instead? `pa11y-ci` now supports reporters, but `pa11y-ci`'s reporters are different from the ones in `pa11y` itself. There's currently two reporters bundled with `pa11y-ci`: the `cli` reporter, and the `json` reporter. You can use additional external reporters not bundled with `pa11y-ci`:
https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y-ci#reporters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @José Luis, `pa11y` and `pa11y-ci` reporters are different.

There is no `csv` reporter for `pa11y-ci`, but there is a bundled `json` reporter.

As for html reporters, there is an `html` reporter included with `pa11y`, but for `pa11y-ci`, you need to download the [pa11y-ci-reporter-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pa11y-ci-reporter-html) npm module.

Reference:

The `pa11y-ci` docs currently refer to the deprecated `pa11y-html-reporter` module, which will not work; I've opened a [PR to update the docs](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y-ci/pull/173).